# Insert into tables values not contained in another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i'm trying to insert data into one table from another

```
INSERT INTO test(CRED_NUMERO, GRP_NUMERO, ARE_NUMERO, CRACTI_NUMERO, CRAC_DIFPORGRUPO, 
JORN_NUMERO, TURN_NUMERO, CRAC_QTDTOTALACESSOS, CRAC_QTDACESSOS, CRAC_VERFSENHA, 
CRAC_VERFDIGITAL, CRAC_ULTPASSAGEM, CRAC_ULTPASSAGEMPONTO)
VALUES ((SELECT PES_NUMERO FROM PESSOAS WHERE PES_NUMERO NOT IN (SELECT CRED_NUMERO 
FROM CRED_ACESSO)),'1', '1', '1', NULL,NULL,NULL,'999', '0', '0', '0',
'2016-08-20 20:02:00.000','2000-01-01 00:00:00.000')
```

However when running the query the following error is shown

> "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression."

I have read previous questions regarding the same error and it is suggested to use "IN" instead of "=", however, the select query has a NOT IN. Could you please help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `insert . . . values`, using `insert . . select`:

```
INSERT . . .
    SELECT PES_NUMERO, ,'1', '1', '1', NULL, NULL, NULL, '999', '0', '0', '0',
           '2016-08-20 20:02:00.000', '2000-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    FROM PESSOAS
    WHERE PES_NUMERO NOT IN (SELECT CRED_NUMERO FROM CRED_ACESSO);
```

Note:  I strongly advise you to use `NOT EXISTS` rather than `NOT IN`.  `NOT IN` returns no rows if `CRED_NUMERO` is ever `NULL`.  The following is just a good habit, so you don't ever have this problem:

```
INSERT . . .
    SELECT pPES_NUMERO, ,'1', '1', '1', NULL, NULL, NULL, '999', '0', '0', '0',
           '2016-08-20 20:02:00.000', '2000-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    FROM PESSOAS p
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 CRED_ACESSO ca WHERE p.PES_NUMERO = ca.CRED_NUMERO);
```